# About the proof of the Ekeland's variational principle

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, nonlinear-analysis

Ekeland's variational principle statement: Let $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ be a Banach space and $f: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{ +\infty \}$ an extended-valued proper lower semicontinuous function, bounded from below. Then for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $x^* \in X$ such that:
\begin{equation*} 
f(x^*) <  f(x) + \epsilon \| x^* - x \| \; \forall x \in X \setminus \{x^*\} \qquad...[1]
\end{equation*}
And for a given $x_0 \in X$, the former $x^* \in X$ can be chosen to meet:
\begin{equation*}
f(x^*) + \epsilon \| x^* - x_0 \| \leq f(x_0) \qquad...[2]
\end{equation*}
According to an article, for the proof of this theorem once [1] is proved, it can be assumed in to obtain [2] with $\hat{f} := f + \chi_{x_0}$, with $\chi_{x_0}$ the indicator function on the set 
\begin{equation*}
X_0:= \{ z \in X: f(z) + \epsilon \| z - x_0 \| \leq f(x_0) \}
\end{equation*}
I have the strong belief that $\hat{f}$ is not necessarily lower semicontinuous. In the opposite case for applied $[1]$ why $x^* \in \chi_{x_0}$? If the recommendation is useless how you can use [1] to prove [2]?

Comment: I think you are right. $f$ is l.s.c. and $\chi_{x_0}$ is u.s.c.. There is no reason why the sum is l.s.c..

Comment: The problem is the definition on the indicator function. If it is defined as the comment below then $\chi_{x_0}$ is l.s.c. indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The function $z\mapsto f(z) + \epsilon \|z-z_0\|$ is l.s.c, so its lower level sets are closed, and the associated indicator function is l.s.c. as well. Sums of l.s.c. functions are l.s.c., so $\hat f$ is l.s.c.

Comment: Why the indicator function is l.c.s.? I am agree that $\chi_{x_0}$ is closed. For a counterexample consider $\chi_{x_0} = [ 0 ,1]$ and  the sequence defined by $x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$. Then $ x_n \longrightarrow x = 1$ and : \begin{equation} \liminf_{n \to \infty}\chi_{x_0}(x_n) = 0 < 1 = f(x) \end{equation}So $\chi_{x_0}$ is not l.s.c

Comment: @Student The indicator function is defined as $I_C(x)=0$ if $x\in C$, $I_C(x)=+\infty$ if $x\not\in C$. It should not be mistaken for a characteristic function, which takes values from $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thanks, with this definition I could prove the implication. I will post it later.